# Can I mine with BFGMiner on an ATI Radeon

Tags: cgminer, gpu, bfgminer, mining-setup

I have managed to connect to the pool via the command line but when I went to manage devices it says I have none. I tried to use auto and all commands to add the GPU and seemingly it will not pick it up.

Is it even possible to use a amd m880g?

Any advice appriciated

EDIT
I have also found the same is true with cgminer. Is it impossible to use this card?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [cgminer-3.7.2](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/tree/v3.7.2) or earlier.  For some reason, GPU mining was removed from subsequent versions.

Cgminer is the best available miner for your purposes.  [Con Kolivas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Con_Kolivas) is one of the world's great programmers, and we are lucky to be able to use his software.

Please also be sure to read the file [SCRYPT-README](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/v3.7.2/SCRYPT-README) to get reasonable performance.

Comment: I've tried 3.7.2 and it still doesn't find my card either.  Is there something special we need to do?

Comment: Actually, this question is even better than your original question, as this is a notoriously difficult point.  The answer is yes,  you need to do a lot of things in this case.

The first thing to do is to download the source code and attempt to build it by following the instructions.  When you configure it,  the software will show you what is missing.  There are a lot of libraries that must be correctly installed, and cgminer will tell you what you have failed to do.

Some people also claim that only certain ati drivers work, but I haven't had that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can if you want to waste energy and time. You should buy specialized hardware, Butterfly labs or Kncminer are two company releasing ASIC miners. Alternatively you can try with cloud mining with [cexio](https://cex.io/r/0/giagola/0/). You can buy and sell GH/s with bitcoins. Receive mining rewards and make a profit on trading. Fees are low as well, only 0.0001 when you will withdraw from the account.