# GPU support on cgminer and bfgminer

Tags: gpu, mac, bfgminer

I just read this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/17980/10116) which states that GPU mining support was removed from cgminer as of version 3.7.2.

Does anybody know what version of bfgminer needs to be used to support GPU mining.

I am currently using bfgminer 3.8.0. On Mac OSX 10.8.5, with an Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you are using is the latest version

It supports OpenCL GPUs.

Which includes Intel HD Graphics 4000.

There is no information of Bfgminer discontinuing GPU support anytime soon.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I should be able to use bfgminer with my GPU?  Any ideas why it would not be working for [me](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17990/10116)?

Comment: Theoretically yes.Although I would not recommend it because you would land up spending more on power than the returns that you would get from your Intel HD 4000.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, however I would like to run it anyhow as a test, as a precursor to purchasing an ASIC device. My GPU is not being recognised however, hence my other [question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17990/10116).

Comment: So why do I get `Disabled.Drivers.....: bfsb cpu knc metabank opencl:sensors proxy:getwork` and `To enable opencl:sensors, install libsensors` at the end of `./configure --enable-opencl`?

Comment: it can't get GPU temps on Mac that's normal. Just use -S opencl:auto when you start or try http://fabulouspanda.co.uk/macminer/